# Worm Identification

Tags: species-identification, species

Please identify the attached worm and larvae. 
Location:  Payette, Idaho 
Approximate size:  1 mm
Found in home.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note:  I have photos of dozens of these, "things."  The samples were gathered using a lint roller.  They are on my bed.  I use a $20 lens with a USB port to my laptop camera.  I am unsure of the magnification.